# Is every limit ordinal an infinite sum of smaller ordinals?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

If $\left\langle \alpha_\gamma : \gamma < \beta\right\rangle$ is a sequence of ordinals of length $\beta$, we define the sum $\sum_{\gamma < \beta} \alpha_\gamma$ inductively as follows:

- If $\beta = 0$, $\sum_{\gamma < \beta} \alpha_\gamma := 0$.
- If $\beta = \delta + 1$, $\sum_{\gamma < \beta} \alpha_\gamma := \left(\sum_{\gamma < \delta}\alpha_\gamma\right) + \alpha_\delta$.
- If $\beta$ is a limit ordinal, $\sum_{\gamma < \beta} \alpha_\gamma := \sup_{\delta < \beta} \sum_{\gamma < \delta}\alpha_\gamma$.

Note that the sum depends on the order of the ordinals in the sequence, and I do **not** require the sequence of ordinals to be increasing.

I would like to know if for all limit ordinals $\alpha$ and ordinal $\beta \geq \mathrm{cf}(\alpha)$, there exists a sequence of ordinals $\left\langle \alpha_\gamma : \gamma < \beta\right\rangle$ such that $\alpha_\gamma < \alpha$ for all $\gamma < \beta$, and $\alpha = \sum_{\gamma < \beta} \alpha_\gamma$?

Comment: Hint #1: Take any sequence of ordinals, indexed by itself.  What can you say about the sum of that sequence?  Hint #2: Extract a sequence from the definition of cofinality.

Comment: @JacobManaker I'm not sure what I can say. Consider $\alpha = \omega + \omega$, and for $n < \omega$ define $\alpha_n := \omega + n$. Then $\sum_{n < \omega} \alpha_n = \omega \cdot \omega$, which isn't close to $\omega + \omega$.

Comment: Yeah, my claim was too strong.  Here's a better hint #1: What can you say about the sum of any sequence of _cardinals_?

Comment: @JacobManaker in that case it's simply the supremum.

Comment: Hint #2 is still valid.

Comment: @JacobManaker I'm not sure if I follow. Also, sum of any sequence of cardinals need not end up being the supremum. Consider $\alpha_n = \omega$ for all $n < \omega$. Then again $\sum_{n < \omega} \alpha_n = \omega \cdot \omega$, which is not a cardinal (we are not doing cardinal addition here).

Comment: Hmph!  This is tricky enough that I'll write up an answer and stop giving misleading hints.

Comment: It's unexciting but true that $\alpha = \Sigma_{\xi \lt \alpha} 1$.

Comment: @BrianO sure, but I believe the exciting part of the question lies in answer for the case where $\beta < \alpha$.

Comment: @ClementYung I agree, but the extreme case I mentioned *is* consistent with the requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that for all ordinals $\alpha\leq\beta$ there is a (unique) $\gamma$ with $\alpha+\gamma=\beta$ and this $\gamma$ is $\leq\beta$. So if $\alpha$ is any limit ordinal and $\langle \alpha_i\mid i<\beta\rangle$ is any increasing sequence of ordinals below $\alpha$ converging to $\alpha$ then there is a sequence $\langle \gamma_i\mid i<\beta\rangle$ below $\alpha$ with
$$(\mathrm{sup}_{j<i}\alpha_j)+\gamma_i=\alpha_i$$
for all $i<\beta$.
An induction shows that for any $i<\beta$
$$\sum_{j<i}\gamma_j=\mathrm{sup}_{j<i}\alpha_j$$
so in particular
$$\sum_{i<\beta}\gamma_j=\alpha$$
Thus there is such a sum of smaller ordinals of length $\beta=\mathrm{cof}(\alpha)$. Any longer sum can be achieved by padding with $0$'s.